# Why hover not working when I include span

Tags: html, css

`.dropdown span:hover .dropdown_content{ display:block }` is not working.

What is the reason???

```css
  *{ padding:0; margin:0 }
  
.dropdown_content{ display:none; }
.dropdown span:hover .dropdown_content{ display:block }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Drop down menu</title>
    <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
     <span>Mouse over me</span>
        <div class="dropdown_content">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's working for me (Chromium 52)..

Comment: Try it in different browser...

Comment: I see that it is working, when i hover i can see 'Hello world' underneath 'Mouse over me'

Comment: Which browser and version you are using?

Comment: Working for me too...

Comment: Guys read question and code, question has one selector while code has different (working) selector

Comment: It *was* working, then the OP edited the code to introduce an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dropdown span:hover .dropdown_content{ display:block }` is not working, because span does not contain `.dropdown_content` element. They are siblings.

Use `+` to select siblings

```css
*{ padding:0; margin:0 }
  
.dropdown_content{ display:none; }
.dropdown span:hover + .dropdown_content{ display:block }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Drop down menu</title>
    <link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
     <span>Mouse over me</span>
        <div class="dropdown_content">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When targeting `span` than you need to target the next `+` adjacent sibling selector like:

```
.dropdown span:hover + .dropdown_content{ display:block }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors